# How to write efficient script to have memory (RAM) peak?

Tags: bash, ram

I have a network with some PCs. I wanted to have peak of the memory for each system.

I wrote a script to check the used memory and writes the peak in a file in `/tmp`; and I've set the script to run in background when the system boots. But it seems that it uses much resources as top shows about 2 (of 8 for 8-threaded CPU) when it runs.

```
#! /bin/bash
touch /tmp/mempeak

while true
do
     A=$(free -m | grep "Mem"|awk '{printf "%.2f",$3/1000-$NF/1000}')
     B=$(cat /tmp/mempeak)
     A=$(awk -va=$A -vb=$B 'BEGIN {print (a>b)?a:b }')
     echo $A > /tmp/mempeak
done
```

I wonder if there is another way to have this value in an efficient way.

PS. The memory peak should reset as the system restarts and should be accessible from remote server by `ssh`

Answer (score 3):

Your script is using a lot of CPU resources because it runs continuously, which is inefficient. To avoid this, add a call to `sleep`, which means that it will only do it's work once every 5 seconds, which is *a lot* more efficient. You can probably extend this to even more, like 60 seconds, depending on how frequent / accurate it needs to be.

Here's what it looks like with that extra `sleep 5`:

```
#! /bin/bash
touch /tmp/mempeak

while true
do
     A=$(free -m | grep "Mem"|awk '{printf "%.2f",$3/1000-$NF/1000}')
     B=$(cat /tmp/mempeak)
     A=$(awk -va=$A -vb=$B 'BEGIN {print (a>b)?a:b }')
     echo $A > /tmp/mempeak
     sleep 5
done
```

If you want to avoid excessive disk writes (e.g. to reduce SSD wear), you could change your script so that it only writes to disk when the value actually changes, and maybe put the output file on a temporary in-memory filesystem as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this way I would miss some values. many times the system memory goes up for just less than a second and it should be recorded in the script.

Comment: @mohammadhmontazeri In that case, you can use a short interval, like `sleep 0.5` or even less.

Comment: Then alter the value to a more moderate `0.5` which is still slower as your script would run uncontrolled.

Comment: @JonasCz: I wonder how the system itself can have for example the CPU load continuously written in some /proc files without any load, but my scripts uses a lot?

Comment: @mohammadhmontazeri that's because the data inside those files in `/proc`  is only generated when you read them. Those files don't actually exist on disk, their content is generated by the kernel when accessed.

Comment: @JonasCz: and is there a way to have a similar way for my purpose?

Comment: @mohammadhmontazeri Not really - but you can do something somewhat similar by using an [in-memory file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188536/how-to-make-a-temporary-file-in-ram), which would avoid disk writes and result in better performance. Your script needs to keep track of the highest memory usage so far, and the `/proc` files don't do something like this. Using a file is the only (easy) way to do this.